# Patch method sample code REST API

Tags: 8

I am working on web services in drupal. I have created a sample module for get method to expose the data using web services. I have not found any sample code for the patch method.
code for get method:

```
namespace Drupal\demo_rest_api\Plugin\rest\resource;

use Drupal\rest\Plugin\ResourceBase;
use Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse;

class DemoResource extends ResourceBase {

}
/**
 * Provides a Demo Resource
 *
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "demo_resource",
 *   label = @Translation("Demo Resource"),
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/demo_rest_api/demo_resource"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class DemoResource extends ResourceBase {

}
/**
 * Provides a Demo Resource
 *
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "demo_resource",
 *   label = @Translation("Demo Resource"),
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/demo_rest_api/demo_resource"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class DemoResource extends ResourceBase {

  /**
   * Responds to entity GET requests.
   * @return \Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse
   */
  public function get() {
    $response = ['message' => 'Hello, this is a rest service'];
    return new ResourceResponse($response);
  }
}
```

I am novice to drupal. I did not find any example for patch method. Can any one usher me or provide a sample code for patch method.